# python boto3 text to speech 'polly'

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-polly

i'm using python 3 and when i try to run my code, i get an error:

```
    raise NoRegionError()
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

my code:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('polly')

output = client.synthesize_speech (
  Text = "Some random text I want to convert", OutputFormat = "mp3", VoiceId = 'Aditi'
)

print(output['AudioStream'])

file = open('speech.mp3', 'wb')
file.write(output['AudioStream'].read())
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to try and add the region name somewhere in the client class.

I.E

```
polly_client = boto3.Session(
                aws_access_key_id=,                     
    aws_secret_access_key=,
    region_name='us-west-2').client('polly')
```

This doesn't necessarily what you intended, but you get the point. the region must be included somewhere

Comment: what should i have to add in the id and the key?

Comment: @Zzz if you already configured your key in your AWS secret files (if you already managed connecting it must mean you have) then try sendinng only the region and see what happens. if you didn't configured anything u need to send your own access key and secret. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/polly.html#Polly.Client.synthesize_speech

Comment: btw, us-west-2 is just an example. I don't know what region you need, you need to check

Comment: polly - text to speech engine

Comment: @Zzz follow this 
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/polly/latest/dg/SynthesizeSpeechSamplePython.html
you can see step 3.1 its about configuration